# How do I create an ECDSA certificate with the OpenSSL command-line

Tags: openssl, certificate

I'm building a server app in C++ that needs to accept a certificate containing an ECDSA public key.  It must validate the certificate and, upon verification, use the public key contained in the certificate to authenticate a message sent along with the certificate.

I have all this working using ECDSA keypairs generated on the fly - i.e. my code is working nicely - but now I need to do the certificate piece.

And I figured I could use OpenSSL's command-line to create the certificate which is installed on the client (along with the ECDSA private key in a separate file).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 66):

If you haven't chosen a curve, you can list them with this command:

```
openssl ecparam -list_curves
```

I picked `secp256r1` for this example.  Use this to generate an EC private key if you don't have one already:

```
openssl ecparam -out ec_key.pem -name secp256r1 -genkey
```

And then generate the certificate.  Your certificate will be in `cert.pem`.

```
openssl req -new -key ec_key.pem -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out cert.pem
```

See also:  [req](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html), [ecparam](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ecparam.html)

Comment: I think you mean `secp256r1`. According to [this post](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/P-256-curve-not-supported-in-openssl-1-0-1-tp5379p5380.html) it is referred to as `prime256v1` in OpenSSL.

Comment: One liner: `openssl req -new -newkey ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:prime256v1 -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out cert.pem -keyout cert.pem`

Comment: Fixed one-liner: `openssl req -new -newkey ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:prime256v1 -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem`

Comment: For a bit more context, see RFC 4492 https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4492 and this recommendations document https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf

Comment: Manpages' links are old, see [req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html) and [ecparam](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ecparam.html).

Comment: One liner with a wildcard domain `openssl req -x509 -newkey ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:prime256v1 -days 3650 \
-nodes -keyout example.com.key -out example.com.crt -subj "/CN=example.com" \
-addext "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:*.example.com"`

Comment: OpenSSL supports NIST curve names, so `-pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-384` is perfectly valid too.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that in order to generate a certificate with ECDSA signature algorithm, not just with ECDSA key you also need to specify the matching hash size.

For example if you generate the **P-384** ECDSA key:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp384r1 -genkey -out ecdsa.key
```

You should specify `-sha384` to generate the self-signed certificate with matching ECDSA signature and hash algorithm:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 36524 -key "ecdsa.key" -sha384 -out ecdsa.crt
```